# Xamarin Button Image not working (NullReferenceException)

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to do an image button on my Xamarin Forms application (shared project configuration).

My XAML is like this :

```
<Button x:Name="btn_params" Image="app_params.png" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Command="{Binding OpenParamsCommand}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"></Button>
```

Because I used shared project configuration, it seems like I cannot have my image within my shared project, so I moved it in the appropriate folder. I'm currently only testing on Android.

I put it in Resources/Drawable on my Android

[image]

This image is marked as compile as AndroidResource, just like Xamarin says in its documentation

When I open this page, I have an NullReferenceException. I know this is this image, because if I remove the Image param, no errors are throwns...

[image]

Any idea of what happens because I have no debug infos other than this exception.

Comment: Try removing Resources.Designer.cs and rebuilding. Are you sure the shared project doesn't contain the image anymore?

Comment: It seems that Resources.Designer.cs moved away from the project, yes. I'll give a shot and let you know

Comment: Was that, I haven't a Resource.Designer.cs on my project !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in comments of my question, it was because I haven't any Designer.Resource.cs on my Resource folder in my Android project.
Adding one just fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your image's **Build Action** is set to **Android Resource**. You can find the setting by right clicking the file in the **Solution Explorer**.

Also, do a Clean/Rebuild (and perhaps reinstall the app) to ensure that all artefacts are deployed properly.

Comment: And I've rebuild, clean, reboot visual, nothing changes

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a custom control to have an ImageButton in Xamarin.Forms . [XLabs](https://github.com/XLabs) has got a nice [widget](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/wiki/ImageButton) to have buttons with images. After adding the [nuget](http://www.nuget.org/packages/XLabs.Forms/) package, you can refer the widget in XAML like below,

```
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:XLabs.Forms.Controls;assembly=XLabs.Forms"
<controls:ImageButton Text="Twitter" BackgroundColor="#01abdf" TextColor="#ffffff" HeightRequest="75" WidthRequest="175" Image="app_params" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Command="{Binding OpenParamsCommand}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
```

Comment: The standard Button can also have images.

Comment: Unfortunaly, same issue with XLabs. That's why I guess it's not a component issue, but with my project/image

Comment: The way you have referred the image is actually correct... It should work. That is why I thought perhaps a different widget might help.